# PHP and mySQL - Why store salt, if crypt() can be used to verify password?

Tags: php, crypt, password-hash

A large number of posts I've seen, regarding password hashing, says something along the lines of:

1. Use a *globally unique* salt for each password
2. Store salts in DB, alongside the hashed password

Dare I even say that this is the *most common* approach outlined?

It all makes sense - if you needed to rehash the input password each time - but in PHP you can use `crypt` to verify a password, without ever using the salt. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135524/comparing-passwords-with-crypt-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top), it is "how it should be done".

For example:

```
$pass = 'YoiI8SjPAlFj';
$salt = '$2y$09$959d78f2f983628c711c7d'; 

echo $hashed = crypt($pass, $salt);

// $2y$09$959d78f2f983628c711c7O3YM7Xdl8Gdnh.S0C.ak41wA8RI1/3ga
```

And then to verify (using same vars)...

```
if(crypt($pass, $hashed) === $hashed) {
    // Success
}else {
    // Fail
}
```

Which will pass, just fine.

If that's the case, then why would I need to store the salt with my password? If the user changes their password, I'll generate a new salt anyway. It seems to me that the salt is superfluous information to store, and just takes-up memory.

Are there any arguments *FOR* storing it? 'Cause I can't think of any.

Comment: You ***need*** the salt if you ever want to recreate and thereby validate the hash. And in fact you are already storing the salt as part of the hash.

Comment: @deceze the link you pointed to is a good explanation. Is there any benefit to removing the salt from the hashed output, and storing the two separately in the same DB?

Comment: Erm… more work, more complications?

Comment: Good enough. Thanks for your input. Too many spook stories about nefarious hackers; it makes approaching security ungodly daunting for us new players.

Comment: Really, you should be using PHP's `password_hash` API, which was specifically created to simplify all this a bit and give you less rope to hang yourself with.